# 100 samples of 20 from the dataset and drawing regression lines along with population regression line

Tags: r, regression, sample

I have a datasetwith two variables hours studied and grade.  I would like to take some 100 samples of 20 each from this data set and show 100 regression  lines along with the original regression line. Any suggestions?

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
grades = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/me6wiww943hzddj/grades.csv?dl=1")
qplot(hours, grade, data = grades, geom = "point") + geom_smooth(method = lm)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop:

```
n=100
for(i in 1:n){
  df = grades[sample(1:nrow(grades), 20),]
  g = g + geom_smooth(method = lm, data=df, color="red", size=0.5, alpha = 0)
}
plot(g)
```

Output:

[image]

I encourage you to mess with the aesthetics of it, adding a dashed line for example:

[image]

Comment: ```g = g + geom_smooth(method = lm, data=df, color="red", size=0.5, alpha = 0)``` in this line how geom_smooth knows the x and y axis variables?

Comment: It uses the arguments you passed to the original plot `g` with `qplot` as default.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `sample_n`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
g <- qplot(hours, grade, data = grades, geom = "point") +
      geom_smooth(method = lm)
n <- 100
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
       tmpdat <- grades %>%
                  sample_n(20)
        g <- g +
         geom_smooth(method = lm, data = tmpdat, color = 'red',
                 size = 0.5, alpha = 0)
    }

plot(g)
```